# maven / eclipse: add tomcat support to imported project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, m2eclipse

I imported a **maven-enabled github project** into eclipse, using **m2eclipse** and the  `Import-> "check out maven projects from SCM`" action.

This maven project also includes a web application module.
After resolving a few dependency issues, it compiled successfully.
Now I'd like to start/debug the web application, using **tomcat**.

What is the **correct way to add tomcat support** for this project without giving up the maven integration (I noticed the *convert facets* action, but I don't think this is the right way to go)?

Answer (score 1):

Since Maven is a build tool the correct way to add tomcat support to your application is not directly specified since it requires deployment relevant information such as deployment descriptors that wont be interpreted by Maven in any way.

There are however plugins such as http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html or http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html available for embedded servers.

Also available are plugins such as http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/ to deploy to a remote server.

Note that i only use the local deployment plugins and dont have any know how about the later.